# HTML CSS DIV margin-top doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu bar that is vertically on the right side of the screen. The menubar should touch the horizontal main navigation bar on the top, but i can't set the top margin of the vertical bar to zero.

Here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/azz5diwqzfchued/Schermafdruk%202015-09-08%2022.22.09.png?dl=0

is a screenshot of how chrome inspect element shows the problem, this might make things a bit clearer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Post code here and would recommend you to create [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net), so you get your solution easy and quick, no one in here would download your file and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the element inspector your margin-top style got a syntax problem.
From the looks of it I'd say you used a double ':' (colon) character.
Try removing the double ':' character and try again.

If this still doesn't work, maybe another style is overriding your new one so you could try:

```
margin-top: 0 !important;
```

This will make sure this style will always have the highest priority.

Comment: I'm so sorry, i completely looked over this. i indeed used 2 colon characters. I fixed it, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Always try to keep an eye out for the yellow rectangles in your element inspector. Saves you a lot of time looking for the cause of a problem.